# Jqgrid Subgrid data fetching from server on expand only

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

I am using Jqgrid (version 5.2.0 ,paid). I am loading the main grid on a button click on the page(aspx page is with masterpage and update panel) and using code to re-instantiate grid and reload grid on button, datatype: local and data='' on grid creation.
I need to load the sub-grid data from server on each main grid row expand only(I will have a lot of data in main grid, loading the sub-grid also on button click is making it slow.)

How to load the subgrid data on row expand?

```
 function createsamplegrid() {
     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
         url: '',
         datatype: 'local',
         colNames: ['Id', 'StoreName', 'Department'],
         colModel: [
    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
    { name: 'StoreName', index: 'StoreName', width: 150 },
    { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 150 }

  ],
         rowNum: 10,
         sortname: 'id',
         viewrecords: true,
         sortorder: "desc",
         caption: "List Employee Details",
         subGrid: true,
         subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
             var subgridTableId = subgridDivId + "_t",
            localRowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowId);
             $("#" + subgridDivId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
             $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                 datatype: 'local',

                 data: '',
                 colNames: ['ID', 'Employee Name'],
                 colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 70, align: "left", hidden: true },
                    { name: 'EmployeeName', index: 'EmployeeName', stype: 'text', align: "left" }
                    ],

                 jsonReader: {
                     root: 'gridModel',
                     repeatitems: false
                 },
                 idPrefix: rowId + "_"
             });
         }
     });
 }

 function GetSampleData() {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'Sample.aspx/GetSampleDetail',
         data: "",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         async: false,
         success: function (Result) {

             var myjsongrid = $.parseJSON(Result.d);
             SampleData = myjsongrid;
             $('#grid').jqGrid('clearGridData');
             $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: myjsongrid, datatype: 'local' }).trigger('reloadGrid');

         },
         error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

         }
     });
 }

 function ReinstantiateGrid() {
     var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
     prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
     function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
     } // fires after the partial update of UpdatePanel
    
     function EndRequest(sender, args) {//Calls the function again to load the grid after  partial postback 
         createsamplegrid();
         GetSampleData();
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Oleg will you be able to help?

Comment: Loading data in subgrid by default is if you expand the row. You do not need to set datatype local in subgrid. Just set data type json and url from where you get the data and the subgrid will load only if you expand the row

Comment: @TonyTomov How to remove the Horizontal scroll bar from Subgrid?

Comment: which scrollbar to remove - those from the main grid when you expand the row or those from the subgrid when is expanded?

Comment: @TonyTomov From the Subgrid when it is expanded(horizontal)

Comment: Set autowidth option to true and shrinkToFit too (for the subgrid), if I correctly understand the problem

Comment: @TonyTomov the scrollbar got removed with autowidth: true,            shrinkToFit: false, but , it made the columns shrink to data size. But I wanted to keep the column width given in the design

Comment: Check the options of the grid like shrinkToFit, autowidth and other related in the documentation section of Guriddo.